# MySQL - Select all rows matching criteria after the last occurrence of a specific value in a column

Tags: mysql

I am relatively new to MySQL (and databases in general) so please bear with me. I have tried looking for parts of the problem elsewhere to stitch together a solution myself, but I guess I am not experienced enough to be able to do so.

So this is the problem:

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
key | account_id | status
1   | 1          | 0
2   | 1          | 1
3   | 2          | 0
4   | 1          | 0
5   | 2          | 1
6   | 1          | 1      <- match (last occurrence of 1, 1)
7   | 1          | 0      <- need to capture
8   | 2          | 2
9   | 1          | 2      <- need to capture
10  | 1          | 0      <- need to capture
```

I have multiple accounts that change their status from time to time. I want to capture all status changes of a particular account from the time the status was last active(1).

The account may have been active in the past, but it may not be currently active. So if you look at the table above, the last time account 1 was active(1) was row 6. I want to capture all status changes from that point onward excluding that line itself:

```
key | account_id | status
7   | 1          | 0
9   | 1          | 2
10  | 1          | 0
```

I have a strong feeling I need to use groupby and a subquery, but I can't seem to come up with a solution.

Comment: "last time account 1 was active(1) was row 6." why not row 2?

Comment: I probably should've mentioned it. The rows are inserted as time moves forward. So row 6 is always further in time than row 2. So row 6 was the last time the account 1 was active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the value of `key` increases with time, this query will give you your desired results. It looks for all entries with `account_id = 1` whose `key` value is greater than the last `key` value where `account_id = 1 AND status = 1`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM accounts 
WHERE account_id = 1 
  AND `key` > (SELECT MAX(`key`)
               FROM accounts
               WHERE account_id = 1 AND status = 1)
```

Output

```
key account_id  status
7   1           0
9   1           2
10  1           0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/45bfg1QgikjR8BiBCJ4iEW/0)

Comment: Wow that was much easier than I expected. Thanks! I am still getting familiar with situations where subqueries are appropriate.

Just out of curiosity, is it possible without a subquery?

Comment: @Suhas I think it would be difficult without a subquery. It might be doable with a JOIN but I think it would be more complicated.